# PostgreSQL INSERT INTO 4 million rows takes forever

Tags: postgresql

I use Postgres 14.1 on Windows 10 for development and I have little experience with Postgres.

Recently, I wrote an `INSERT` query to copy records from one table to another.
The source table has less than 4000K records.
The problem is that the query takes forever to run in `pgAdmin` and hits timeouts in my app, no matter how large the timeout limit is.
I can't paste the real query but it is a simple "insert if not exists" construct:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) 
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS T1 WHERE table2.refid = T1.refid)
```

Data selection part itself takes few seconds but with the `INSERT INTO` takes forever.

I tried to remove all indexes and constraints from the target table but it did not change anything. I have tried to limit SELECT result and it runs fine.

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c) 
SELECT a, b, c 
FROM table2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 AS T1 WHERE table2.refid = T1.refid) 
LIMIT 4000000
```

What is the magic behind LIMIT threshold which is above the actual number of records in the source table?

The current `postgresql.conf` is as follow:

```
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 2GB
effective_cache_size = 6GB
maintenance_work_mem = 512MB
checkpoint_completion_target = 0.9
wal_buffers = 16MB
default_statistics_target = 100
random_page_cost = 1.1
work_mem = 6990kB
min_wal_size = 1GB
max_wal_size = 4GB
max_worker_processes = 6
max_parallel_workers_per_gather = 3
max_parallel_workers = 6
max_parallel_maintenance_workers = 3
```

**UPDATE**

After few retries, deleting all rows, and inserting again, the query runs fine without the LIMIT statement and completes within 20 seconds. Still curious what could cause the issue.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The answer you pointed to is different, the op has performance issues and far more records to insert. I agree that in such cases one statement can not perform well. My case is a bit different. Why INSERT with LIMIT 4000K takes few seconds and without does not complete. Please note that the source has less than 4000K

Comment: It may just be a matter of lack of resources (memory) for the full one. Everything you do on your database runs within a session, meaning everything is being stored to be fully committed at the end of the process. That's the reason I suggested the batch execution

Comment: Available RAM on server, available disk space, avg row size and cardinality of both tables before the insert? Concurrent operations (in the db cluster and on the whole db server)? `pg_stat_activity`, `pg_locks`, and the physical size of tables might also allow insights. Finally, hardware issues?

Answer (score 1):

If `refid` is among the columns to be inserted, the best solution would be to use `INSERT ... ON CONFLICT`:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (a, b, c, refid)
SELECT a, b, c, refid
FROM table2
ON CONFLICT ON (refid) DO NOTHING;
```

That requires a unique constraint on `table2(refid)`.